# Delphi and iPhone PVR files

Tags: iphone, delphi

I have interesting question.

Do you know of any component to read/write PVRTC iPhone files in Delphi?
A PVRTC file is a file that is compressed using the PVRTC format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google has uncovered the [PVRTexLib](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtexlib.asp) library, which can be converted using the [header conversion tools](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10281) into .pas files which can be linked to your application, and then you just use the relevant .dll with your application.

These are not direct delphi components, but it should be possible to convert the data that is produced from reading the library into a delphi bitmap image.